# typescript subscribe refresh onsubmit metod

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

product-generic.service.ts

```
constructor(
    private genericParaBirimi: GenericService<ParaBirimi, 0>,
) {
    //#region List
    this.genericParaBirimi?.Get_All("ParaBirimis/Generic_Method").subscribe((x: any) => this.paraBirims = x);     
}
```

first-price-list.component.ts

```
constructor( 
public productservice : ProductService) { }
this.genericParaBirimi?.Post(this.ParaBirimForm.value, "ParaBirimis/Generic_Method").subscribe({
  next: (data) => { },
  error: (err) => { },
  complete: () => {
    
    Refresh parabirims in html
  }
});
```

first-price-list.component.html

```
 <p-autoComplete formControlName="ParaBirimiID" [suggestions]="filteredParaBirimi"
                    (completeMethod)="filterParaBirims($event)" field="paraBirim" [dropdown]="true">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of productservice.paraBirims" class="country-item">
                        <div>{{item.paraBirim}}</div>
                    </div>
                </p-autoComplete>
```

How can I use a method to automatically update the page without refreshing the page after adding to the parabirims list?

Comment: is it not working by just assigning new data to the previous list ?

Comment: constructor( 
public productservice : ProductService) { }Since I added it in the constructor, a new list appears only when I refresh the page.

Comment: @EnesNizam then add constructor part code to ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first things we need to do is keep the `paraBirimi` state contained in the service. By design, you shouldn't be calling API requests from any components.

The next thing is to package your GET and POST updates into a single observable that components can subscribe to. Let's get into the code.

Service File

```
public paraBirimis$: Observable<ParaBirimi[]>;
private addParaBirimi = new Subject<ParaBirimi>();

constructor(private http:HttpClient){
  this.paraBirimis$ = this.http
  .get<ParaBirimi[]>(`${environment.url}/ParaBirimis/Generic_Method`)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(api => this.paraBirimiUpdate.pipe(
      scan((list, new)=>[...list, new], api),
      startWith(api)
    )),
  );
}

public postParaBirimi(payload) {
  this.http
  .post<ParaBirimi[]>(`${environment.url}/ParaBirimis/Generic_Method`, payload)
  .pipe(
    tap(newParaBirimi=>this.addParaBirimi.next(newParaBirimi))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Our public observable `paraBirimis$` first gets data from the GET endpoint. Then we switchMap into a `Subject` which will emit any new paraBirimi that are created from our POST request. The `scan()` operator is similar to `.reduce()`, but for values emitted from observables. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan In short, we're taking values emitted from our `Subject`, and adding them to our state array via the spread operator.

Because `Subject`s do not emit anything to begin with, we include the `startWith()` operator to have it emit our GET API request as the first value.

Next, we need our Subject to emit new values after POST requests. We create a public method that triggers our POST request, and then use `.next()` so the `Subject` will emit that new value, triggering the `switchMap()` in our public observable.

With the reactive pipeline setup in our service, our components can be quite simple, as our observables will automatically update any state mutations. The only new thing we need to include is a method that calls `postParaBirimi()` in our service.

Component TS

```
this.paraBirims$ = this.productservice.paraBirims$;

public postParaBirimi(){
  this.productservice.postParaBirimi(this.ParaBirimForm.value);
}
```

Component HTML

```
<p-autoComplete
  formControlName="ParaBirimiID"
  [suggestions]="filteredParaBirimi"
  (completeMethod)="filterParaBirims($event)"
  field="paraBirim"
  [dropdown]="true"
>
  <div *ngFor="let item of paraBirims$ | async" class="country-item">
    <div>{{item.paraBirim}}</div>
  </div>
</p-autoComplete>
```

And that's it. You component has one active subscription to the observable we created in our service. Invoking the POST event in our service will cause that same observable to emit a new list with the newly created value.